# EntityFrame Work Core how to use Select Case similar to sql

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda

I have a query in sql like this :

```
Select 
    sum(case when OperationType = 1 then 1*ProductCountMain when OperationType = 2 then -1*ProductCountMain end) As Result
From Inventories
```

How can i write this in lambda expression in EntityFramework core.

Comment: Have you tried using the ternary operator, `?:`? Eg `Inventories.Sum(i=>i.OperationType==1?ProductCountMain:-ProductCountMain)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) for this (`?:`) :

```
var total=myContext.Inventories.Sum(i=>i.OperationType==1
                                      ?ProductCountMain
                                      :-ProductCountMain);
```